# Keep Node Server running "watching" for things to occur

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I think this question is due to a lack of understanding on node, but i'm working on created a motion sensor with the raspberry pi and node.

I don't understand how to keep my node server running.  I can get it to work as intended using `setInterval` but I don't think this is how I should be doing it.

Basically I want to be able to start the program with `node index.js` and have it continue watching the GPIO pins that the sensor is connected to see if something happens.  If something happens then it does something, but keeps watching the sensor in case more happens.

What I have done to keep it running is similar to this:

```
var foo = require('require necessary things up here');

setInterval(function(){
  //code for detecting sensor stuff here
}, 1000)
```

This works, but I know I don't think it's the right way to do it.

If I do something like the below it just executes the functions, logs to the console, but doesn't watch for changes and just exits out.

```
var foo = require('require necessary things up here')

function checkForSensorStuff(){
  //code for detecting sensor stuff here
  console.log('checking stuff')
}
```

How can I keep the server running so that it just continually watches for changes in a function without using setInterval?

Comment: Can you define (in words, in code..) what "*continually watches for changes*" means? How do you expect that to happen?

Comment: @Amit The sensor emits `0` when it's in its normal environment.  When it detects something it emits `1`. I want the program to continually run and check to see if the sensor emits `1`.

Comment: Again, define "*continually run*". Continually do what?

Comment: @Amit check if the sensor emits `0` or `1`

Comment: So you want a loop? Use a loop...

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but either what you have or [something like this](https://gist.github.com/MartyWallace/37982597531e9310ec5ed889cba4877f) seems perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4):

A node process exits when it has nothing else left to do.  You start a node process by running a startup script line by line.  When that script finishes executing, if there's nothing else to do (no timers, no open sockets listening for incoming connections, etc...), then it shuts down because there's nothing left that could cause an event and cause some action on the server.

So, if you want your server to continue running, you have to give it some way for future events to occur.  As you've discovered a recurring timer is one way to do that.  There should be no reason to use a timer purely for keeping your server running.  Instead you need to configure something in your server that will trigger events in the future.  If you don't have anything that will cause future events, then you may need to use `setInterval()` to regularly poll some status to decide if there's something waiting to do.

If you're trying to monitor GPIO status on your Raspberry Pi in node.js, you can use the [pigpio library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pigpio) and it will offer an event driven way of watching for GPIO changes.  This should automatically keep your server running.

Another option for getting events upon GPIO changes is the [onoff library](https://github.com/fivdi/onoff).

I have a Raspberry Pi being used as a temperature controller that reads two GPIO temperature probes.  I'm just using a `setInterval()` timer to poll the temperature readings every 10 seconds and that works just fine too.

Comment: @Elliott McNary - Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how to keep my node server running

You need to open an handle to a resource like a socket or a file. If there is no active handles opened, node exits. In your example setInterval is timer which prevents node to exit.

see also process._getActiveHandle

https://github.com/myndzi/wtfnode

Comment: This explains why the process ends but doesn't answer the question of how best to retain it, which is what the OP is after specifically.